# How to add verification to discord.js bot v12

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm somewhat new to coding and I am making a bot in discord.js v12 and I was wondering how I could add verification for new users who join the server. Weather than be sending them a captcha they must complete or just adding a reaction role that they click and it gives them x role such as "member" or "verified." Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

I have actually just recently created one of those using a very simple method of creating two questions and answers arrays and checking if the user's input matches the answer.

So, first off you'll want to create 2 arrays:

```
const questions = ['Do you like melon?', 'Do you want melon?']
const answers = ['Yes!', 'What do you want from me...']
```

Then you can get a randomized question that would match the answer:

```
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length)
var randomQuestion = questions[randomIndex]
var randomAnswer = answers[randomIndex]
```

And finally, you can send the question and check if the answer matches:

```js
message.channel.send(randomQuestion)
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === randomAnswer) {
        let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Member")
        message.member.roles.add(role)
        message.channel.send('Congratulations! you've completed the verification!');
   } else {
       message.channel.send('Verification failed. Incorrect answer.');
   }
});
```